# How to apply a media query to all but one device

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to do a media query to all but one device. I am working with a confusing css code base that did not do breakpoints properly and would like to select all devices that fit a min-width except one device (ipad in my case)

Something like this: if the first condition is not true then do not continue

```
 @media not only screen 
 and (min-device-width : 768px) 
 and (max-device-width : 1024px), (max-width: 823px) {
 ...
 }
```

Sort of like this in javascript `if(something && somethingElse)`, ie. only continue if the first condition is true.

I'm afraid, after reading that media queries are separate entities that this is not possible but am checking to see if someone has a work around for this that does not include copying and pasting all the code into another media query after the initial one to reset back.

Thanks!